Is there any order of precedence in window functions of SQL?
I have a table as follows:
I just want the previous entry for every row from the column 'marks'.
Table structure:
 test_id    marks 
   100        55
   101        55
   102        60
   103        58
   104        40

This is my query:
select *,LAG(marks,1,marks) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prev

from student_tests


This is the output:

      test_id    marks 
        100        55
        101        55
        102        60
        103        58
        104        40


The output is as per my expectation. But, I am unable to figure out if it makes sense when I give 1 as the offset in the part LAG(marks,1,marks) along with the window.
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

Because, I am in the sense asking SQL to look 'UNBOUNDED' PRECEDING and then giving 1 in the offset doesn't seem sensible to me.
If my understanding is correct, query must have given me the error. But, it didn't.
So, I am wondering whether there's any order of precedence on the play under the hood.
Am I missing something?
Please help me understand this.

Edit: Respecting the Stackoverflow policy, I have removed the images and tried alternatives.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The WINDOW syntax is used for other analytic functions too. So, UNBOUNDED PRECEDING only relates to the window within which the analytic function can look. The 1 then says to look back one row, if possible, within that window.  You can partially simulate LAG(x, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) with FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z ROWS BETWEEN 1 ROW PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Is there a reason you aren't specifying an ORDER BY for the LAG() window-function? Otherwise the "preceding row" is undefined... (I'm surprised Postgres doesn't throw an error here, actually) - unless I'm misunderstanding something?

@Dai Actually, there isn't any specific reason as such. I just didn't have need to use 'order by' in this case.
But FYI the following query yields the same output.
select *,LAG(marks,1,marks) OVER (ORDER BY NULL RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prev from student_tests

@MatBailie made the edits to remove images . lets go stackoverflowinggg

@DevarapalliVamsi ORDER BY NULL doesn't do anything useful so it isn't what you want - I assume you want the rows in ascending chronological order (so LAG(p,1) returns the previously added row - and I assume test_id is a sequence/identity column, so use ORDER BY test_id.

The lag and lead functions are special, in that they ignore the frame clause. So it makes no difference if you specify ROWS or RANGE or what the window is. It always just looks forwards or back the specified number of rows. You can prove this by looking at results from the lead function. In most other DBMSs it's not even valid to specify a window frame for lead and lag.
The default window specification is in any case RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, so it's not necessary to specify it even in functions where it does make sense. Moreover, RANGE is almost never what you want, you nearly always want ROWS.
Furthermore, lag and lead only make sense with a unique ORDER BY specification, otherwise "Without ORDER BY, rows are processed in an unspecified order". As always in SQL, if you do not specify ORDER BY then all bets are off.
The default number of rows is 1, so it's not necessary to specify it unless you also want to specify the default value.
So a more normal-looking lag call would be
LAG(marks, 1, marks) OVER (ORDER BY test_id) as prev


That's a very detailed answer. It made lot of my beginner doubts resolved. I even got to know that RANGE and ROWS are different (Googled the difference).
Regarding ORDER BY, Eventhough I did get the same results using ORDER BY NULL and not using it at all, it seems to be a good practice to not mess up things in the long term.
Coming to 'ignorance' of frame clause, what's the reason is it included when anyhow it would be ignored.

@DevarapalliVamsi It only worked without ORDER BY because it depended on Postgres returning rows in the same order they were inserted, which you can't depend on. I'm just surprised Postgres lets you execute unsound queries like this without generating any warnings.

@DevarapalliVamsi I can't say why it's allowed, probably to make the parse/lexer's job easier. ORDER BY NULL would return the same results as not ordering at all i.e. completely arbitrary. The fact it usually returns correctly is no proof, you must give an ORDER BY if you want deterministic results.
